# Constraint Layout correct margin and size for different screen support

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to build a layout using ConstraintLayout. I need to every view to adjust themselves according to the screen size without the need for a scroll view.

This is my current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/colorBackground"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:background="@drawable/home_gradient_animation_list"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_app_intro"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"/>

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/donorAnimation"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:lottie_fileName="lotte_animation_place.json"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/donorAnimation"
            android:id="@+id/donorTextLayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/home_gradient_2_2"
                android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:text="Got extra food? Get on board and help serve the food to people in need"/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/volunteerAnimation"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:lottie_fileName="lotte_animation_food_delivery_1.json"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/donorTextLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/volunteerAnimation"
            android:id="@+id/volunteerTextLayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/home_gradient_2_2"
                android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:text="Not everyone gets a chance to server their community. Become a volunteer and help us deliver the food."/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/recipientAnimation"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            app:lottie_fileName="lotte_animation_food.json"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/volunteerTextLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            app:lottie_loop="true"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            app:cardElevation="2dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recipientAnimation"
            android:id="@+id/recipientTextLayout">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/home_gradient_2_2"
                android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_bold"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:text="Whether you are a religious place or a non-profit organization, we have you covered."/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"

            app:layout_constraintWidth_max="250dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/btn_start"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:id="@+id/btn_start_main"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/avenir_bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/home_gradient_2_2"
                    android:text="Start"/>

            </FrameLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how it looks on different screen size device:

Works Fine here
[image: Works Fine here]

Layout goes beyond bottom
[image: Layout goes beyond bottom]

What constraint can I use along with size so that the layout adjusts its size to fill the screen?
ImageView is set to wrap content so that it can adjust.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set the Motion Layout as the parent view (Instead of Relative Layout)

Then you can do vertical chain constraints with the buttons and images. That'd do it. Actually this is what I've done to solve the same problem.